# What is the call for when an enemy air-to-air missile has been fired?

Tags: military, usa, phraseology

In a scenario where a large multi-crewed aircraft was being attacked by a fighter that launched an air-to-air missile what would the call be that would alert the pilot that a missile was in the air and potentially tracking them.  I know the term 'Rifle' but I always assumed that meant a friendly missile in the air, is there a specific call for an enemy missile?

Also is there a call for a SAM launch?

Comment: Any particular country?

Comment: Ideally the USA

Comment: "Get me out of here"

Comment: Have you read the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiservice_tactical_brevity_code)?

Comment: I did but there didn't seem to be an air-to-air missile specific entry

Comment: Is there a reason that you didn't ask for the Russian version of this?

Answer (score 4):

From an older NATO book on brevity words that I have, a hostile guided missile is VAMPIRE.

A hostile surface to air missile is, indeed, SAM.

**Edit.**
From the [better list](http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA404426) of brevity words

```
VAMPIRE  Hostile anti-ship missile
```

So VAMPIRE is not an air to air missile.
My old list did not specify the type of the hostile missile.

Comment: As I recall, that was for surface to surface missiles.  (But it's been three decades since I had all of those memorized, so don't take that as gospel).

Comment: [Link](http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA404426) to brevity codes

Comment: A vampire is the term for an incoming anti-ship missile, not an air to air missile or ground attack missile.

Answer (score 0):

When you see an enemy missile or its smoketrail you call out SLAMEYE with your position and the direction to the missile.

For hostile cruise missile launch its QUAIL.

Hostile radar lock on you is called out as SPIKED.
For example: SPIKED 4 o'clock

Comment: Could you provide sources for these?

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/167065842/Joint-Brevity-Words-Publication-App-07e

Comment: Your article is behind a paywall on a website selling documents it doesn't have resale rights for, aka piracy and intellectual property theft.